# Explain C++ pointer initialization

Tags: c++

```
int value = 3;
int *pValue1 = &value;
int *pValue2(pValue1);
cout << (*pValue1) << " " << (*pValue2);
```

In the above code if you have noticed I have written

```
int *pValue2(pValue1);
```

instead of

```
int *pValue2 = new int;
pValue2 = pValue1;
```

Still it is working and giving proper result. 
Can any one explain to me which of the default function or constructor is getting called in this case?

Comment: Why is this tagged `c++11` and `c++14`?

Comment: *Still it is working* - Your other way doesn't work; it leaks memory. You allocate new memory and then immediately make the one thing pointing to it point elsewhere.

Comment: because i am working on visual studio 2013. And I don't know if it is related to c++11 or c++14

Comment: @Nihar you can see c+11 or c++14 as "upgrades" for the core-C++-language. Since you don't use "special" functions, ... like lambdas which would relate dependend on the usage to C++11/C++14, your question needs for that reason to be only tagged with c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *pValue2(pValue1);
```

is equivalent to

```
int* pValue2 = pValue1;
```

Just assign to `pValue2` `pValue1` (assign to `pValue2` address of variable `value`).

Answer (score 1):

The difference should be apparent if you print the pointers themselves (the addresses) in addition to the values which they reference:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int value = 3;
    int *pValue1 = &value;
    int *pValue2(pValue1);
    int *pValue3 = new int;
    cout << pValue1 << " " << pValue2 << " " << pValue3 << endl;
    cout << *pValue1 << " " << *pValue2 << " " << *pValue3 << endl;

    pValue3 = pValue1;
    cout << pValue1 << " " << pValue2 << " " << pValue3 << endl;
    cout << *pValue1 << " " << *pValue2 << " " << *pValue3 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You will also see that after `new int`, the memory pointed to by the pointer contains uninitialized data.